# ayuda con consulta symfony 3

Tags: symfony3, dql

Hola resulta que estoy trabajando en un proyecto en symfony 3.3 y tengo una Entidad que tiene campos como

- titulo (string)
- auto (booleano)
- createdAt (datetime)
- ftope (datetime), esto último es una fecha tope

y quiesiera hacer una consulta en mi repositorio que me devolviera los elementos con un orden similar a esto

primero los que tiene el campo auto en true si la fecha tope aun esta vigente y luego el resto en orden descendente por la fecha de createdAt

se podrá hacer todo esto en una sola consulta o eso se debe hacer en la vista con twig?

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar en la consulta

```
$qb->addOrderBy('column1', 'ASC')
   ->addOrderBy('column2', 'ASC')
   ->addOrderBy('column3', 'DESC');
```

como si fuera una consulta sql normal y corriente

Answer (score 0):

Intenta con esto

```
//crear el query

//agregar lo siguiente
$query
    ->addSelect("IF(DATE(NOW()) < ftope AND AUTO, 0, 1)  AS HIDDEN ORDEN");
    ->orderBy('ORDEN', 'ASC');
    ->orderBy('createdAt', 'DESC');
```

Hay una referencia a columnas hidden [acá](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html) y [acá](https://michelsalib.com/2012/03/04/doctrine2-ninja-with-the-hidden-keyword/)